# Youtube channel section videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I am successful in fetching my channels Home page sections with **"youtube.channelSections.list" API** how do i fetch the videos inside these sections ? i have been successful in fetching playlist and the videos inside the playlist

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelSectionListResponse",
 "etag": "\"QVyS2yjpsZ-tKkk4JvgYeO_YkzY/w_jkjA-XySSniIDLSdSp4NytWyw\"",
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "youtube#channelSection",
   "etag": "\"QVyS2yjpsZ-tKkk4JvgYeO_YkzY/UqkgurncwAQUZJghxpaiPZEtEFk\"",
   "id": "mychannelid.ebKlgRwnpFY",
   "snippet": {
    "type": "channelsectionTypeUndefined",
    "style": "horizontalRow",
    "channelId": "mychannelid",
    "title": "MGR Movies",
    "position": 0
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

the above json gives me my section **"MGR Movies"** how do i fetch the videos inside it ?

Answer (score 2):

Daniel:

I'm diving that question now. So far I'm having no luck funding a *list* resource for *channelSections*.

The one thing I see is that you can add *contentDetails* to your part request and you will get playlist Ids for sections that are in fact playlists.

```
youtube/v3/channelSections?part=snippet,contentDetails
```

This won't help with other sections in the list, like recent uploads or popular or such.

The resulting block will look like the following:

```
contentDetails: {
    playlists: [
        "PLC76EE07063D0854B"
    ]
}
```

The array here worries me a bit as it seems they would allow for more than 1 playlist to be tacked together for a section either now or the future. This will definitely make a pull of the listed videos more complicated.

I'll keep diving and report back with any other mechanisms I see.